# onload hiding of dojo

Tags: dojo, dialog

Using [this](http://www.tutorials4u.net/dojo-tutorial/dojo_tooltips_dailog_example.html) as a learning tool, and I modified as below, it still shows.  How can I hide it before the user sees the page.  This is a similar problem with srciptalous Element.fade that even with a function call in onLoad I cannot hide it before the user sees.  TIA.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojo.require("dojo.parser");
  dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
  dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
  dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
  //dojo.addOnLoad(showDialog);
  dojo.addOnLoad(hideDialog);
  function showDialog() {
    dijit.byId('dialog1').show();
  }
  function hideDialog() {
    dijit.byId('dialog1').hide();
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend using that tutorial due to various reasons.

1. Dojo changed his syntax a lot and is using an asynchronous approach now. This means a lot of the syntax changed since Dojo 1.7. Even worse, the syntax you're using now will disappear in version 2.0.
2. It's generally considered a bad practice to use `<table>` elements for creating layouts. Tables should only be used to display tabular data.

But as an answer to your question, you can define a property called `data-dojo-props="open: false"` in your dialog, but it's weird that it opens already since normally it's closed by default.

If you also want to hide the HTML before Dojo loads, you can add a `style` attribute like this: `style="display: none"`. This will make sure the HTML is not displayed to the user until the `show()` function is called on your dialog.

I also made a JSFiddle (and updated the syntax a little bit), [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9PtTF/2/) is the result.

Comment: Thank you for a complete answer and and edification.  I timidly ask how would do such an example with the newer Dojo syntax and structure.  Again thank you

Comment: Where are you getting that error? On the JSFiddle? Which browser are you using?

Comment: But I am getting "registry.byId() is undefined" loading as below.  Just saw your reply, thank you.  I am getting in my testing.
    <script src='<html:rewrite page="/pages/js/dojo/dojo1.7.5/dojo/dojo.js..."></script>
    <script src='<html:rewrite page="/pages/js/dojo/dojo1.7.5/dijit/dijit.js"/>' ..."></script>
    require(["dijit/registry", ..."], function(registry, ready) {
      ready(function() {
        registry.byId("btn").set('onClick', function() {
          console.log("test");
          registry.byId("dialogOne").show(); 
        });
      });
    });
Sorry still dk how to format

Comment: You can't highlight that much in comments, but it auto-highlights when you indent your code or when you click the code button in your editor. For small code blocks you can use accents ``. But the reason why it isn't working is because I added a custom button called `btn` to display the popup (in my test). Remove that part of the code and it will probably work.

Comment: Okay, but if I wanted to call it programatically wouldnt I have to call it the same way?  Why isnt dojo finding an html button with that id?  How else are you supposed to access elements.

Comment: I didn't use an HTML button but a Dojo (`dijit/form/Button`) button. You can see that by viewing the HTML part of my JSFiddle. 
I connected an `onClick` event handler to that button which will pop up the dialog.

Comment: Yes, I understand and it is elegant, but for my edification then how is a dijit/form/Button to be accessed if it is failing in this clear and simple deployment?

Comment: Is it failing in the JSFiddle too? If it isn't, then show your HTML and JavaScript code.

Comment: I guess the tutorial you are asking for in your first comment is this one : http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dialogs_tooltips/